# Añadir ceros dependiendo de la cantidad de numeros

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una duda en php o javascript es posible añadir cierta cantidad de ceros dependiendo de la cantidad de numeros que tenga, es de aclarar que el maximo de caracteres es de 8, ej:
a = 1 para añadirle serían 7 ceros a=00000001
a= 20 -> a=00000020
A=110 -> A=00000110

Saludos...

Comment: Si se puede, tomando en cuenta que esto solo se podría hacer para datos de tipo string, ya que para datos de tipo número los ceros a la izquierda son desechados, y el número tendría su valor original sin estos.

Comment: JavaScript o PHP??? De a una pregunta por vez es la idea, sino no estarías en condiciones de elegir la mejor... Perfectamente podés realizar 2 preguntas en el sitio, una para cada lenguaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función de PHP `str_pad`que puedes encontrar en el siguiente enlace: http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php

Un ejemplo de uso sería:

```
const MAX = 8;

$s="1";
echo str_pad($s, MAX-count($s), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;

$s="20";
echo str_pad($s, MAX-count($s), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;

$s="110";
echo str_pad($s, MAX-count($s), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me sirvió...